# Oracle SQL query comparing multiple rows with same identifier

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm honestly not sure how to title this - so apologies if it is unclear.

I have two tables I need to compare. One table contains tree names and nodes that belong to that tree. Each Tree_name/Tree_node combo will have its own line. For example:

```
Table: treenode
| TREE_NAME | TREE_NODE |
|-----------|-----------|
| 1         | A         |
| 1         | B         |
| 1         | C         |
| 1         | D         |
| 1         | E         |
| 2         | A         |
| 2         | B         |
| 2         | D         |
| 3         | C         |
| 3         | D         |
| 3         | E         |
| 3         | F         |
```

I have another table that contains names of queries and what tree_nodes they use. Example:

```
Table: queryrecord
| QUERY   | TREE_NODE |
|---------|-----------|
| Alpha   | A         |
| Alpha   | B         |
| Alpha   | D         |
| BRAVO   | A         |
| BRAVO   | B         |
| BRAVO   | D         |
| CHARLIE | A         |
| CHARLIE | B         |
| CHARLIE | F         |
```

I need to create an SQL where I input the QUERY name, and it returns any ‘TREE_NAME’ that includes all the nodes associated with the query. So if I input ‘ALPHA’, it would return TREE_NAME 1 & 2. If I ask it for CHARLIE, it would return nothing.
I only have read access, and don’t believe I can create temp tables, so I’m not sure if this is possible. Any advice would be amazing. Thank you!

Comment: Why ALPHA would return 1&2 both? It should return only 1

Comment: That is my mistake, I will edit the OP. Alpha should be ABD, and in that case it will return both. Thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: By the way, if you want [the new SO table formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support?cb=1), each table needs to be in its own code block - currently the `Table: treenode` etc headings are preventing them being rendered as HTML tables. I'd edit but I'm not sure whether it's what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group by` and `having` as follows:

```
Select t.tree_name
  From tree_node t 
  join query_record q
    on t.tree_node = q.tree_node
 WHERE q.query = 'ALPHA'
Group by t.tree_name
Having count(distinct t.tree_node)
       = (Select count(distinct q.tree_node) query_record q WHERE q.query = 'ALPHA');
```

Comment: This can't be right. Test it and you will see. Here is the general (theoretical) reason: assuming the "nodes" for a given "query" are distinct, the full outer join will produce exactly the rows from the `treenode` table, plus several "outer" rows where the `tree_name` is `null`. So, when you group by `tree_name` and count "distinct" `tree_node` (distinct is not needed), you will get exactly the count of rows for each `tree_name` from the first table. This has nothing to do with which nodes, for each tree, are or are not found in the second table for a given `query`.

Comment: Ok @mathguy, Got you. Updated the answer now!!

Comment: I would need to find some more test cases to verify, but this returned exactly what I expected for the situation I had! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a `join` and aggregation.  The trick is to count the number of nodes in `query_record` before joining:

```
select qr.query, t.tree_name
from (select qr.*,
             count(*) over (partition by query) as num_tree_node
      from query_record qr
     ) qr join
     tree_node t
     on t.tree_node = qr.tree_node
where qr.query = 'ALPHA'
group by qr.query, t.tree_name, qr.num_tree_node
having count(*) = qr.num_tree_node;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=57e26409f7c4543730e6d11a586f6e44) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Tried this out, but it is returning any 'Tree_name'  that contains *some* of the tree_nodes, but not necessarily all of them.

Comment: @OliverKrett - Something is wrong on your end - either your testing or your data. I just tested this solution for `'CHARLIE'`; as expected, it returns no `tree_name`, even though trees 1 and 2 have some nodes in common with `'CHARLIE'`. Are there duplicate rows in either table, in the data you are testing on? That's the only "data" explanation that comes to mind for what you reported, both for Gordon's answer and for mine (which, I believe, are both correct).

Comment: @OliverKrett . . . I added a db<>fiddle showing that this does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Using an `IN` condition (a semi-join, which saves time over a join):

```
with   prep (tree_node) as (select tree_node from queryrecord where query = :q)
select tree_name
from   treenode
where  tree_node in (select tree_node from prep)
group  by tree_name
having count(*) = (select count(*) from prep)
;
```

**`:q`** in the `prep` subquery (in the `with` clause) is the bind variable to which you will assign the various `QUERY` values at runtime.

**EDIT**

I don't generally set up the test case on online engines; but in a comment below this answer, the OP said the query didn't work for him. So, I set up the example on SQLFiddle, here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b575e/2

A couple of notes: for some reason, SQLFiddle thinks table names should be at most eight characters, so I had to change the second table name to `queryrec` (instead of `queryrecord`). I changed the name in the query, too, of course. And, second, I don't know how I can give bind values on SQLFiddle; I hard-coded the name `'Alpha'`. (Note also that in the OP's sample data, this `query` value is not capitalized, while the other two are; of course, text values in SQL are case sensitive, so one should pay attention when testing.)

Comment: So I tried this out and it is not working. I need to know all tree_name that contain the necessary nodes, but I don't care if it contains more nodes than the query in queryrecord specifies. I believe this is only returning results if the tree_name contains the EXACT tree_nodes that the query specifies

Comment: @OliverKrett - I tested this before I posted it, and it returns the correct answers for me. I will set up the data and the query on a SQL engine site for you to check for yourself. Regarding your belief - it is incorrect. Notice the `where` clause? It only allows the rows from the `treenode` table that have `tree_node` in the list of tree nodes for the given `query`. Any other nodes the `tree_name` may include are left out by the `where` clause, before aggregation and count. I wonder how you tried this out. Anyway - on to setting this up for you.

Comment: @OliverKrett - I added an **EDIT** at the bottom of my answer, with a link to the SQLFiddle test case. You may change the `query` value from `'Alpha'` to `'BRAVO'` or `'CHARLIE'` (or `'ECHO'` for that matter, to see what happens then). Please pay attention to capitalization - the sample data you provided was inconsistent. I hope that is not why the query didn't work for you.

Comment: Okay, I think I may have transcribed something incorrectly. Looking at the results, this leads me to another question. So I now realize that in the tree_node table, there is also a 'parent_node_name'. Right now the results are telling me what TREE_NAME encompasses the necessary TREE_NODEs. I also need to pull in what the parent_node_name column says, which should be the same for all tree_node rows (when they match the query name)

Comment: @OliverKrett - You know your problem better than we do. If it feels like the question is really different (even though related), then you would be best served by asking it in a separate thread (you can reference this thread, if it's relevant). On the other hand, it's possible that the problem is essentially the same - just replace `tree_name` with the composite `(tree_name, parent_node_name)` where relevant.

Comment: I'm not sure that it warrants a new thread. I'm having trouble getting the parent_node_name added, as I'm not sure how to add it to the group by clause. I can't simply add it to the select, as it is not an aggregate value.

Comment: @OliverKrett - then EDIT your question (you can see one way to add an EDIT in my answer, above). Explain exactly what is "new" (compared to the original question) - additional column or columns in the table, with sample data, and restate the requirement to reference parent nodes as well.